# How to add a link to a local html file(Bokeh figure) in Overleaf

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, ref

I have a Bokeh figure which is saved locally as a html file how do I add a link to it in Overleaf?

I've tried:

```
\href{run:C:/---path---/file.html}{LINK}
```

To no avail.

Comment: overleaf can not connect to your machine (unless you run a public web server on your machine) upload the file to a public web server if you want the link to work from anywhere or leave it as a local file link and then it will work if you download the generated PDF back to your machine, it won't work at overleaf (or anywhere else other than your machine)

Comment: I've uploaded the file to the project but I'm ensure how to add a link to it \href{run:file.html}{LINK} doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry I noticed later it was an html file, I changed my initial comment.

Comment: Hi Dom, Tom from Overleaf support here. By uploading a file into an Overleaf project, it's not made available on the internet, so it's also not really possible to link to it from the PDF produced by your project. You can insert links to HTML files into the PDF file (e.g. using `\url{http://...}` when both `url` and `hyperref` packages are added), but you need to make that file available somewhere on the internet and then use the file's URL. Overleaf doesn't provide such functionality. I hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm trying to make it available on the internet using github. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize comments. It not possible to insert local html files directly in Overleaf. However if the file is made available somewhere on the internet you can use `\url{http://...}`. I did this by uploading to [github](https://github.com/) and following these simple [steps](https://www.finex.co/how-to-display-html-in-github/).